# Does anyone else support Umbridge?

Tags: harry-potter

So while reading on-line it seems that there is a strong hatred towards Madam Undersecretary Professor Dolores Jane Umbridge. I just want to know if anyone else supported her ideals within the book? The fact she did her best for Hogwarts and the Ministry and was ultimately punished for doing all she could to fix in place legal and sensible ideals?

Anyone else think of characters who may have supported her?

Comment: Are you asking about readers (real-world) supporting her, or characters in-universe supporting her?

Comment: If you're asking for opinions of readers, the question is out of scope for the site, as we're not set up for discussions (chat is, though). If you're asking for characters in the books, I'd venture to say that most Death Eaters generally supported her.

Comment: I believe you mean Madam UNDERsecretary Professor to the BlahBlahBlahBlah ;)))))) I'm just joking with you --  :)

Answer (score 20):

Yes, you will find that **Argus Filch** the caretaker supports Professor Umbridge.

Argus Filch have been wishing to use corporal punishment on the students for a long time, as *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets* chapter 8 explains.

> Harry had never been inside Filch's office before; it was a place most students avoided. The room was dingy and windowless, lit by a single oil lamp dangling from the low ceiling. […] A highly polished collection of chains and manacles hung on the wall behind Filch's desk. It was common knowledge that he was always begging Dumbledore to let him suspend students by their ankles from their ceiling.

Professor Umbridge finally allows that in *Order of the Phoenix* chapter 29:

> ‘Quickly, quickly!’ he hared a wheezy voice mutter right outside the office door. ‘Ah, she's left it open –’
>
> Harry dived for the Invisibility Cloak and had just managed to pull it back over himself when Filch burst into the office. He looked absolutely delighted about something and was talking to himself feverishly as he crossed the room, pulled open a drawer in Umbridge's desk and began rifling through the papers inside it.
>
> ‘Approval for Whipping … Approval for Whipping … I can do it at last … they've had it coming to them for years …’
>
> He pulled out a piece of parchment, kissed it, then shuffled rapidly back out the door, clutching it to his chest.
>
> Harry leapt to his feet and, making sure he had his bag and that the Invisibility Cloak was completely covering him, he wrenched open the door and hurried out of the office after Filch, who was hobbling along faster than Harry had ever seen him go.
>
> [Later, in the Entrance Hall where Fred and George are caught on wrongdoing.] Filch elbowed his way closer to Umbridge, almost crying with happiness.
>
> ‘I've got the form, Headmistress,’ he said hoarsely, waving the piece of parchment Harry had just seen him take from her desk. ‘I've got the form and I've got the whips waiting … oh, let me do it now …’
>
> ‘Very good, Argus,’ she said. ‘You two,’ she went on, gazing down at Fred and George, ‘are about to learn what happens to wrongdoers in my school.’

Comment: Others on this list would include; Minister for Magic Cornelius Fudge, who appointed her to this position; Voldemort and his Death Eaters, as they directly benefit from her interfering with Dumbledore's plans and preventing the students from learning how to defend themselves; Draco Malfoy and his Ilk who hated basically every teacher and student Umbridge did.

Comment: @b_jonas, perhaps you should expand your answer, incorporating the information in the comment above.

Answer (score 3):

Known people that supported Dolores Umbridge in specificity:

- Argus Filch
- Inquisitorial Squad (Draco Malfoy, Pansy Parkinson, Millicent Bulstrode, Vincent Crabbe, Gregory Goyle, Graham Montague, Cassius Warrington)
- Yaxley (Member of the Muggleborn Registration Commission) - Appointed by Umbridge and seen talking with her in the Ministry.

People that may have supported Umbridge in general:

- Lord Voldemort - There is no evidence that Umbridge ever became a Death Eater or spoke with him personally.
- Lucius Malfoy - While they were on friendly terms, there is no evidence that he directly supported her other than possibly being approving of her Ministry actions
- Cornelius Fudge - There are some signs (His appointing her to higher positions in the Ministry) that he supported her, but nothing concrete. According to the HP wikia, she is rumored to have played on his paranoia as well which may have contributed.
- Rufus Scrimgeour - Also, no direct evidence, but he did leave her in her position.
- Pius Thicknesse - Left her in her position, but unknown how much of that was due to actual support or effects of the Imperius curse
- Death Eaters - In general, they may have supported her for her anti Muggle stances, but no specific statements to this fact.
- The unnamed members of the Wizengamot that voted to convict Harry during his trial. Unknown if they did this out of support or fear, however.

[Rowling's essay on Umbridge](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/dolores-umbridge)